# "easily fooled" in Chinese(slang)

Tags: vocabulary, slang, spoken

例如, 一个人无论如何也学不会1+1=2怎么计算的时候可以说: 那个人智商 (真是) **低**的**发指**, 怎么教都教不会.

问题: 汉语中有类似的句子描述一个人很容易上当受骗吗? 句型: 这么简单的骗术你都信, 你 (真是) XXX.

XXX中不能有人身攻击, 必须切实到被描述者的真实情况. 在上面句子中"**那个人智商 (真是) 低的发指**, 怎么教都教不会"前半句"客观"的描述了后半句的起因, 而不是一句骂人的气话.

最后, 我知道这个问题不是很礼貌.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一般这种词都有贬义。如果委婉一点，我们可以说: *这个人头脑太简单了*。

> 问题: 汉语中有类似的句子描述一个人很容易上当受骗吗? 句型: 这么简单的骗术你都信, 你(真是)XXX.

In this case, we can say: 你太容易上当了 or 你太好骗了. 你太傻了 or 你太笨了 might sound derogatory.

Comment: Both are good answers, Yours' best! https://i.stack.imgur.com/74D7C.png

Comment: @K. Broflovski  I thought you want "slang"?

Answer (score 1):

很蠢、很笨、笨笨的、呆呆的、没脑子、智商低、白痴、很傻、很呆、脑子不太灵光 etc etc

it depends on the context to decide which one to use...

I don't think 智商低的发指 is commonly used...发指 normally refers to someone/something very bad.

Answer (score 1):

> [羊牯](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/35291/)
> [n] an innocent fool, **someone easily duped**, an ordinary person (lit., "castrated sheep")

~

> [水魚](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/14362/)
>
> (2) **a dupe**; **a sucker**; target or victim of a (pecuniary) fraud; to be tricked (Cantonese only)

A person can't learn 1+1 = 2 is a [弱智人士](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/26976/) or [智障人士](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/26178/)

羊牯 and 水魚 are slang, for common phrase, a person that is easy to trick is being **好騙**

*"令人发指" means "outrageous" . Not a suitable word to use for "弱智人士/ 智障人士"*

Comment: Both words for Cantonese only. Most mandarin speakers won't know.

Comment: @Shiji.J 羊牯  is Mandarin : Example: From 鹿鼎記第四回 -- 韋小寶留神他的手勢，登時放心：『此人是個羊牯！「在他心中，凡是不會行騙的賭客，便是羊牯。

Comment: Uh, just because it’s written in *The Deer and the Cauldron* doesn’t make it Mandarin, in fact the book was first published in Hong Kong of all places. Both words you’ve given are strictly Cantonese.